# How to use getText inside a div and store it in a varaible in Cypress

Tags: cypress

```
cy.xpath('some xpath').then(($btn)=>{const text = $btn.text()})
```

I am currently using like this but i can use the text only inside .then() so i have problem of calling it outside .
Please tell me how to get the text and store in a variable.
e.g. var text= cy.xpath('some xpath') like this so that i can use it anywhere in inside the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alias using `as` ([cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as)) to store your innerText.

```
cy.xpath('some xpath').invoke('text').as('text')
```

Now later if you want to use it you can use it like:

```
cy.get('@text').then((text) => {
    //Do something with text
})
```

Comment: Happy to help @KalpanaS.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that all alias are cleared between tests.

This means if you do this

```js
it('checks some xpath', () => {
  cy.xpath('some xpath')
    .then(($btn) => { return $btn.text()})
    .as('myvar')
})

it('uses myvar', () => {
  cy.get('@myvar').then((myvar) => {   
    const newvar = myvar + '2'          // FAILS - "alias myvar has not been declared
  })
})
```

Some better ways

**Use alias from `this` scope**

```js
it('checks some xpath', () => {
  cy.xpath('some xpath')
    .then(($btn) => { return $btn.text()})
    .as('myvar')
})

it('uses myvar', function() {         // note "function"
  const newvar = this.myvar + '2'     // this.myvar is set by alias but NOT cleared
})
```

**Use "back-flip" variable**

```js
let myvar;

it('checks some xpath', () => {
  cy.xpath('some xpath')
    .then(($btn) => { return $btn.text()})
})

it('uses myvar', () => {         // arrow function is ok
  const newvar = myvar + '2'     // myvar is global to both tests
})
```

Comment: Thanks KKhan I tried to use                  commonMethod.enterEmailAndLogin(this.loginPage, username, password)
      cy.wait(2000)
      cy.xpath('(//span[contains(@class,"title ng-scope")])[1]')
      .then(($btn) => { 
        return $btn.text()
      })
      .as('myvar')
      cy.log("------"+this.myvar)                                                                                         
  like this its returning undefined how to call this myvar inside the same it().